# if $\lim_{z\to 0} zf(z) = 0$, then $f(z)$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am trying to prove 4 implies 3 in the riemann removable singularity theorem:

> **Theorem.** Let $D\subset\mathbb{C}$ be an open subset of the complex plane, $a\in D$ a point of $D$ and $f$ a holomorphic function defined on the set $D\setminus\{a\}$. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $f$ is holomorphically extendable over $a$.
> 2. $f$ is continuously extendable over $a$.
> 3. The exists a neighborhood of $a$ on which $f$ is bounded.
> 4. $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)=0.$

So we can say the following :

Let $M$ be a positive constant such that $|f(z)| \leq M$ for all $0 < |z| < \delta$.

Now, for any $z$ with $0 < |z| < \delta$, we have

$$|f(z)| = \frac{1}{|z|}|zf(z)| \leq \frac{1}{|z|}M.$$

Now the right hand side still blows up to infinity near 0 so I'm not sure how to get that $f(z)$ is bounded.

Comment: Did you have a look at the proof in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity ? The implications 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 are trivial, and 4 -> 1 requires some work.

Comment: @MartinR yes ive seen the proof. I just want to prove 4 implies 3 as a practice to see if I can do it and for some reason, it's a bit trickier than I thought.

Comment: $(z-a)f(z)$ has a power series expansion around $a$. What is the constant term in it?

Comment: @geetha290krm did you mean laurent series? f is a priori not assumed to be holomorphic at the point $a$ so for all we know, it might be a singularity.

Comment: $(z-a)f(z)$ has a removable singularity and it does have a power series expansion around $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While all the implications $(1) \implies (2) \implies (3) \implies (4)$ are “trivial” or “obvious” in the sense that they follow easily from the definitions, the implications in the other direction are not.

It is not “obvious” that $\lim_{z\to 0} zf(z) = 0$ implies that $f$ is bounded in a neighbourhood of the origin, and (as you saw) can not be proven by estimating
$$
|f(z)| = \frac{1}{|z|}|zf(z)| \leq \frac{1}{|z|}M \, .
$$

All implications in the other direction use the special properties of holomorphic functions, and their proofs always boil done to proving that any of $(2), (3), (4)$ imply that $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=a$.

So in order to show that $(4) \implies (3)$ one shows that
$$
 (4) \implies (1) \implies (2) \implies (3)
$$
where $(4) \implies (1)$ is the non-trivial part. As demonstrated in [Wikipedia: Removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity), this is done by proving that $(4)$ implies that
$$
h(z)={\begin{cases}(z-a)^{2}f(z)&z\neq a,\\0&z=a.\end{cases}}
$$
is differentiable at $z=a$, therefore holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $z=a$, and satisfies $h(a) = h'(a) = 0$. Then $h$ can be developed into a power series whose coefficients start with $(z-a)^2$, which leads to a holomorphic extension of $f$.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. apologies for taking so long to get back as I was so busy I never had time to read se these few days.